Нужно каждый раз делать npm run build, чтобы увидеть изменения в next js
Я использую next js, у меня есть вторая страница, и чтобы увидеть на ней изменения нужно делать npm run build.
Это код package.json:
{
  "name": "tvoe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.2.13",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "sass": "^1.79.3",
    "swiper": "^11.1.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.13",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


А next start не работает?

Чтобы видеть изменения в реальном времени в NextJS есть возможность запуска проекта через npm run dev. Это позволит запустить проект в режиме разработки, что будет заставлять перерендревать страницу каждый раз, когда происходит како-то вмешательство или изменение в проекте. В NextJS есть три режима запуска проекта:

dev — запускает Next.js в режиме разработки. 23 Для этого нужно выполнить команду npm run dev или yarn dev. 2
build — запускает сборку приложения для производственного использования. 2
start — запускает производственный сервер Next.js. 2 Перед этим приложение нужно скомпилировать с помощью команды next build.

Так-же на эту тему есть оф. обширная документация: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/cli/next
